# Is there a shortcut/variable tag for an Assets field’s ‘parent’ entry title?

Tags: matrix, assets, pixelandtonic

I have an Assets field in a Matrix field. When I'm inside the Assets field's loop, is there a shortcut tag to output the 'parent' entry's Title field (1.1 in the hierarchy below)?

1. Entry

   1. Title
   2. Matrix field

      1. Assets field

Or do I have to use an embed?

I ask because I recall Pixel & Tonic used to document all kinds of variable tags for Playa such as `{parent:title}`, that still work but are now *undocumented*.

I've tried a few such ideas in my Assets loop to see if I could get lucky but no joy so far.

Comment: An aside: the Assets field is only in a Matrix field because there is no `{if no_results}` equivalent in Assets that I know of :(

Comment: It's probably also worth adding that the Entry at the top of the hierarchy above is in fact being called within a `{playa:parents}` loop within a `{zoo_visitor:details}` tag, which might screw up the shortcut tag if there is one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doh! The answer is to use the *documented* `var_prefix` parameter so I can then reference the entry's `{title}` field as normal :$

That Brandon fella has thought of (nearly) everything :)

Comment: Don't you just hate that guy? :)